# Redirect old dynamic url to a new pattern using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

A normal link of my site may look like this

**mydomain.com/categorylist/8/Special_Single_Songs.html**

I'm planning to change the URL pattern to something like

**mydomain.com/categorylist/8-Special-Single-Songs.html**

How can I redirect the old URL pattern to the new one using .htaccess redirect rule?

My .htaccess Rewrite rule look like this

```
RewriteRule ^categorylist/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html$ /index.php?pid=$1&sort=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
RewriteRule ^categorylist/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ /index.php?pid=$1&sort=$2&page=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^categorylist/([0-9]+)\-([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ /index.php?pid=$1&sort=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this & put it on top after RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule ^categorylist([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*).html$ $1-$2 [L,NE]
RewriteRule ^categorylist([^_]*)_([^_]*).html$ /$1-$2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

note :  big number of underscores can be a problem